# Are there any performance effects of using radiation hardened memory units?

Tags: memory, flash, radiation

Are there any performance related effects of using radiation hardened memory units as compared to non-hardened ones having the same configuration except the protection it should provide from radiation damage? (read write speed, date reliability)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RADHARD ICs generally have a dual encoding and a parity; however, some encode 4 bits as 6 bits so that you have encoding schemes where you are fine even if you lose a bit.  Without giving the specific IC, I can say that you'll most likely use more power, but the biggest issue is that these IC cost much more.

Comment: It will very probably only be available in slower speed grades, as well.